# Checking for new lines in a string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, newline

Can anyone tell me why this isn't working? It always returns `false`.

```
$str = "huuhhu\r\n\r\nmoo.com\r\nwww";

if (preg_match('/(\\n|\\r\\n|\\r)/', $str) === true) {
    echo "True";
} else {
    echo "False";
}
```

Comment: Just a note: you don't need the double-escapes for the regex since you're using single quotes. `'/(\n|\r\n|\r)/'` will work too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`preg_match` doesn't return `true`. It returns the number of matches. You need to do this:

```
$str = "huuhhu\r\n\r\nmoo.com\r\nwww";

if (preg_match('/(\\n|\\r\\n|\\r)/', $str)) {
    echo "True";
} else {
    echo "False";
}
```

Also, you could probably simplify your expression to this:

```
'/\n|\r\n?/'
```

Comment: Sorry php n00b here, but surely if(0) is false in php and if(1),if(2),if(3) etc. are true as in almost any other language?

Comment: Yes. But using `===` takes into account `type` as well, and an `integer` is not the same type as a `boolean`. You can do `== true` if you like, but that's just the same as ignoring it all together.

Answer (score 2):

preg_match() returns the number of times pattern matches and `FALSE` if an error occurred. It never returns `true`.